# Docker, Rails and Sidekiq - bundler: command not found: sidekiq - Running sidekiq as a separate container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, sidekiq

Trying to setup my environment with sidekiq, already have a redis container up and running.

But sidekiq container gives me this error when I try to get it up.

`bundler: command not found: sidekiq Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'`

my docker-compose file:

```
    sidekiq:
      container_name: app-sidekiq
      build: .
      command: bundle exec sidekiq
      depends_on:
        - redis
      volumes:
        - .:/app
      env_file:
        - .env
      networks:
        - app-network
```

my .env file has:
`REDIS_URL=redis://limpar-api-redis:6380`

My app's Gemfile currently has the sidekiq gem.

When I go into my app container bash and start sidekiq from it, it starts up just fine.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV NODE_VERSION 12
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /home/app/app/current

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs postgresql-client yarn build-essential vim

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . $INSTALL_PATH

RUN rm -rf tmp

RUN useradd -Ms /bin/bash api -u 1001
RUN chown -R api:api /home/app /usr/local/bundle
USER root


EXPOSE 3100
CMD rails server -p 3100 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Any step missing from my docker files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the `bundle install` step is missing from your `Dockerfile`. I'd suggest sharing the contents of said file to help debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Piotr Usewicz, Added my docker file to the question. I do have a bundle install step on it though.

Answer (score 0):

Running a `docker-compose build --no-cache sidekiq` and `docker-compose build --no-cache app` fixed it for me! It only needed to be rebuilt apparently.